# JQuery - AJAX - Click Div to Display SQL Data Relevant to ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to dynamically display helpful Notes on screen to users.

If you go to http://discovertheplanet.net/general_notes.php

The list on the left is how many rows there are in my Notes table.

There are three columns in my database, '*NoteID*', '*NoteName*' and '*Note*'

Each '*NoteName*' is pulled from the database and is given an ID using the '*NoteID*' column in the database

**The PHP/HTML:**

```
<div class="main-container-notes">
    <div id="left-box">
        <?php 

        echo "<div style='width: 100%;'>";

        while( $noteName = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $resultNotes, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
            echo "<div class='hvr-bounce-to-right1 hover-cursor output' data-noteid='{$noteName['NoteID']}' style='width: 100%; border-right: 5px solid #00AA88; height: 50px;'>" . $noteName['NoteName'] . "</div>";
        }

        echo "</div>";
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="right-box">

    <!-- Where the actual full note description will go -->

    </div>
</div>
```

My current script: which is in my `<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>`

Looks like:

```
$(".output").click(function() {
    var noteid = $(this).data("noteid");
    $("#right-box").load("connectionDetails.php", { noteid: noteid });
});
```

**EDIT**

This is my connectionDetails.php:

```
<?php
$myServer = "replacement";
$connectionInfo = array('Database' => 'DiscoverThePlanet', 'UID' => 'replacement', 'PWD' => 'replacement');

//connection to the database
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($myServer, $connectionInfo)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

//Test connection to server
// if ($conn) 
// {
//     echo "connection successful";    # code...
// }

//Defining my queries
$getNotes = "SELECT NoteID, NoteName, Note FROM Notes";
$getTemplateNotes = "SELECT TemplateNoteID, TemplateNoteName, TemplateNote FROM TemplateNotes";
$getReplaceVariables = "SELECT ReplaceVariableID, ReplaceVariableName, ReplaceVariableNote FROM ReplaceVariables";

$resultNotes = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $getNotes );
$resultTemplate = sqlsrv_query($conn, $getTemplateNotes);
$resultVariables = sqlsrv_query($conn, $getReplaceVariables);

if( $resultNotes === false) 
{
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
if( $resultTemplate === false) 
{
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

if( $resultVariables === false) 
{
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

?>
```

Not sure if it affects anything but i also have this included like so

```
<?php include 'connectionDetails.php'; ?>
```

So am i on the right lines as I'm new to this, and how do I now use the ID's I have, to pull through the *'Note'* column when I **click** on the appropriate Div?

**Example**: I click on 'Test note' which has a *NoteID* of 1 it then checks the *'Note'* column for *NoteID 1* and pulls through 'This is a test piece of helpful text shown in my right container on the same screen'

I hope I have explained this well enough, if you need any more info, please just ask.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: So what is your issue? Seems like what you are doing is right. Do you have any problems?

Comment: Yes, i'm not sure where to go from here. It sounds silly but ive got to here and just have a mind blank as to how to now get the notes to show on the same page.

Comment: What you are doing should load whatever connectionDetails returns back.

Comment: I will edit my post and show my connectionDetails.php

Comment: Ok ive edited it, i also dont have anywhere in my piece of script anything about pulling through 'Note' because im not sure where i add this in

Comment: So you pass up the `noteid` to the php, but you do not use it?

Comment: Yes, i believe thats the case, im trying to use that id to display the correct note when you click on the note name

Answer (score 0):

i think make a ajax call is easy then your way 
try this :

```
$(".output").click(function() {
    var noteid = $(this).data("noteid");

    $.get("connectionDetails.php?id="+noteid, function(data, status){
    $("#right-box").html(data);

});

});
```

in you php code try `$_GET['id'];` to get noteid value